# Cannot start TeamCity

Tags: macos, installation, teamcity, integration

I am trying to run TeamCity for a first time on Mac OS X Yosemite, I followed the online instructions, but it doesnt work. I have unzipped the file on my desktop and navigate in the terminal, but it doesn't recognize the command start or it says **"Looking for installed Java..."** when I write **./runAll.bat**
How can i configure this? I have a lesson today and I need to install TeamCity.
Please help.
Here is a screenshot:
[Screenshot of terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vh3f3.jpg)